# How to persist the camera parameters into SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, camera

How to keep checkbox state and settings for camera after the destruction of activity?

Or in other words, how to persist the camera parameters into SharedPreferences?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.menu_old);
SharedPreferences preferences = 
getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

yourCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById( R.id.fonarb );
yourCheckBox.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("lol",false));
yourCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()

{
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton   yourCheckBox,
        boolean isChecked) {
     if (isChecked){

         Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
         params.setColorEffect(Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
         camera.setParameters(params);


     }
     else {     
         Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
         params.setColorEffect(Parameters.EFFECT_NONE);
         camera.setParameters(params);

     }

}


});

public void onStop(){
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
 editor.putBoolean("lol", true);


 editor.commit();
 super.onStop();
}
```

---

Did as you said, does not want to save settings! : (

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("qwe",MODE_PRIVATE);
    yourCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById( R.id.fonarb );
    yourCheckBox.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("lol",false));
    yourCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()

    {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton   yourCheckBox,
            boolean isChecked) {
         if (isChecked){

             Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
             params.setColorEffect(Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
             camera.setParameters(params);



         }
         else {     
             Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
             params.setColorEffect(Parameters.EFFECT_NONE);
             camera.setParameters(params);

         }

    }


    });









    protected void onPause()

   {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("qwe",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    yourCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById( R.id.fonarb );
    editor.putBoolean("lol", yourCheckBox.isChecked());
    editor.commit();
        super.onPause();
     }
```

Comment: What's the problem? Do you need to work out how to persist the camera parameters into SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of always storing "true" in the SharedPreferences, simply store the current state of the CheckBox.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
CheckBox yourCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById( R.id.fonarb );
editor.putBoolean("lol", yourCheckBox.isChecked());
editor.commit();
```

You also might consider moving this code to onPause() instead of onStop().  The operating system (pre-Honeycomb) can kill your activity once it has been paused without ever calling onStop().  If that happens, your SharedPreferences will not be saved.